# Offline mode Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

i am creating this function to set my image which is stored in firebase storage and works fine but when the simulator is offline , it doesn't go through my default local saved image

```
func downloadImageFromFirebase(_ imageNameOnFireBase: String, _ defaultLocalImageName: String, _ imageToBeReplaced: UIImageView) {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let reference: StorageReference = storage.reference().child(imageNameOnFireBase)
    let defaultImage = UIImage(named: defaultLocalImageName)
    reference.downloadURL { url , error in
        if error != nil {
            imageToBeReplaced.image = defaultImage
        }else{
            if let url = url {
                do {
                    let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)
                    imageToBeReplaced.image = UIImage(data: data)!
                } catch {
                    print("Error fetching URL")
                    imageToBeReplaced.image = defaultImage
                }
            } else {
                imageToBeReplaced.image = defaultImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can i make the function take the local image if the simulator or the device is in offline mode ?

Comment: What exactly does this code do, if not what you expect?

Comment: it works as expected when working online , i am wondering why isn't working offline ? what is wrong in my code  to take the default image in case of offline ( error is not nil )

Comment: Are you asking if data stored in Firebase Storage is cached? Unless something has changed, no, Storage Data is not cached so you can't load data from Storage when you're offline. For a solution see [download to a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_to_a_local_file)

Comment: No no , my question is much simpler than that , i have a UIImage view , i fill it's image from images stored in my firebase storage file . all i want is when the user is not connected to internet ( so won't be able to download these images ) then get the default image stored locally in the app !

Comment: It's unclear what code is/is not running. Does this execute `print("Error fetching URL")`? If you add a print statement within the `if let url = url {} else {` does it print? Can you clarify where the code is not working as expected? Adding a breakpoint here `if error != nil` and stepping through the code line by line may be revealing.